# ¿Como limpio la cache de mi proyecto de visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un problema y la verdad no sé a que se deba y yo creo que es debido al caché que pueda llenarse en mi proyecto, pero no sé como borrar la caché de mi proyecto en .net.

Ya que actualmente hago cambios, muy pero muy basicos de mi código como borrar metodos importantes que deberían hacer que la aplicación dejará de funcionar pero corro la aplicación y todo sigue funcionando y hago esto pues porque ningún cambio que haga me lo realiza y hay un .ashx que se realiza de forma extraña ya que las primeras líneas de código se ejecutan de manera vertical y después de la tercera se van ejecutan hacia arriba y hacia abajo de manera aleatoria, ese .ashx se manda llamar mediante una llamada ajax y no esta dentro de ninguna estructura de control como el FOR o el While.

Comment: "y todo sigue funcionando y hago esto pues porque ningun cambio que haga me lo realiza y hay un .ashx" -> por eso creo que es un proyecto web. De casualidad has visto la caché del navegador?

Comment: @fredyfx si lo eh borrado varias veces, aunque los problemas son a nivel de servidor y no de estilos. Gracias

Comment: intenta reiniciar el sitio desde el IIS

Comment: Limpia la solución, dale clic derecho, luego en Clean y luego en Rebuild para que genere nuevamente las DLLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- Si lo pruebas en el navegador, debes limpiar el cache del navegador(ctr + shift + suprimir)

2.- Debes limpiar solución:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- En caso que sigas con el problema, debes eliminar los archivos temporales:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Sobre lo ultimo, el punto 3, puede ser la carpeta Framework o Framework64, dependiendo del bit de tu computador.

http://www.programandoamedianoche.com/2008/09/eliminar-archivos-temporales-de-aspnet/

https://geeks.ms/jalarcon/2010/09/17/archivos-temporales-de-compilacin-de-asp-net/